# Twitter sign in oauth api keeps redirecting me to authorize application

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm working with twitter oauth and am having issues with twitter demanding me to authorize the usage of the application even if i have already authorized the application. For example, i authorize the usage of the application, log out, and then go to the login for twitter it asks me again for authorization of the usage of the application. Note my question is in regards to keeping me to authorize the application not the authentication area i imagine once the authorization issue is fixed the authentication of twitter will work.

The flow should be:

1./ User authorizes with twitter.

2./ Twitter sends to callback

3./ Callback performs database interaction for saving user and authenticating user with application

4./ Callback redirects to homepage

5./ User logs out of application (all session data destroyed)

6./ User re-logs in with twitter, and twitter should not reauthorize but recognize the user and redirect to application which should authenticate somehow from twitter possibly matching oauth tokens from a database?

Not sure if this is applicable, but if i even go to twitter login just after doing the authorization, it still asks me to reauthorize

Here's my code:

**twitter login code**

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(twitter_apikey,twitter_apisecret);
$request_token= $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => "https://example.com/twittercallback"));
$_SESSION['oauth_token']=$request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']=$request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$url = $connection->url("oauth/authorize", array("oauth_token" => $request_token['oauth_token']));
header('Location: '. $url);
```

**And here's my callback code:**

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$oauth_access_token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$oauth_access_token_secret = $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(twitter_apikey,twitter_apisecret,$oauth_access_token , $oauth_access_token_secret );
$access_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'], 'oauth_token'=> $_GET['oauth_token']));
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(twitter_apikey,twitter_apisecret, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$user_info = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials',['include_email'=>'true']);
$oauth_token = $access_token['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
print "<pre>".print_r($user_info,true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: Your web server maintains session with the client. `User logs out of application (all session data destroyed).` This means the user will need to re-authenticate with Twitter as you are no longer saving the tokens in session state.

Comment: @JohnHanley authentication is not the issue. the issue is it asks to reauthorize

Comment: @JohnHanley updated question

Comment: As it should. Why do you think it should not ask for reauth? You would need to implement SSO for that feature.

Comment: Once i authorize the usage of the application, if i log out and click on the twitter login , it should not ask me to authorize the application again

Comment: @JohnHanley i think you're confused. im speaking about authorizing the usage of the application not the authentication process. this should only occur once

Comment: OK - that part was not clear in your question. Use the wording "Reauthorize application" instead to make the issue clearer.

Comment: @JohnHanley i updated my question thanks for the comment

Comment: If I solve this problem for you, are you willing to release the bounty?

Comment: @itsben unfortunately the answer supplied worked. sorry hes getting the bounty when available.

Comment: @jkushner I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect the user to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate` instead of `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize`

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/authenticate.html

Change this line

```
$url = $connection->url("oauth/authorize", array("oauth_token" => $request_token['oauth_token']));
```

to

```
$url = $connection->url("oauth/authenticate", array("oauth_token" => $request_token['oauth_token']));
```

Comment: So simple. I thought the authenticate occurs after authorization. Thanks for the help.